# Update app from google play programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

In my app I have a link. When clicking on the link, I want to send the user to Google Play and update the app automatically.

I tried this:

```
// package name from menifest: com.infibond.infi
public void installInfiApplication(View view){
    final String apkurl = "market://details?id=" + "com.infibond.infi";
    final Uri marketUri = Uri.parse(apkurl);

    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(marketUri);
    startActivity(promptInstall);
}
```

But this sent the user to the store without updating the app.

Is there a way to do it? If yes then what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Google does not currently provide a way to automatically start updating an app through an Intent. It seems unlikely that they ever will since it takes control of app installations away from users. Users can however enable auto updates for your app to get updates as soon as they are available unless the update requires new permissions (pre Android Marshmallow).

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can you show me where you got that?

Comment: This part of the developer docs talks about linking to things in Google Play [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html). It doesn't address what you are asking, but if Google was going to give instructions that would be a logical place for it. Moreover the market generally puts users in control, they approve permissions, they manage their apps, they can turn auto update on or off, etc. Allowing devs to automatically start updates violates that established model, and could potentially force users to install malicious software through an update.